# NSOperation that will operate on UIView launches before layoutSubviews is called

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, uiviewanimation

Say I have a subclass of `UIView` which I will call `AnimatableView`, where my implementation of `layoutSubviews` lays out some internal content.

`AnimatableView` also has the method `commenceAnimationLoop` which looks something like this:

```
- (void) commenceAnimationLoop {

    NSOperation *animationLoop = [[AnimationLoopOperation alloc]init];
    [queue addOperation:animationLoop]; //queue is a NSOperationQueue iVar of AnimatableView
    [animationLoop release];
}
```

The `AnimationLoopOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation` whose `main` method will start an infinite animation which only exits once the `isCancelled` property becomes `YES`.

The problem I am having is in my `ViewController` where I setup and animate an instance of `AnimatableView` like so:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    AnimatableView *animatableView = [AnimatableView alloc]initWithFrame:someFrame];

    [self.view addSubview: animatableView];
    [animatableView commenceAnimationLoop];

    [animatableView release];
}
```

The problem is that the `NSOperation` created in the `commenceAnimationLoop` executes before my instance of `AnimatableView` has had chance to call `layoutSubviews` (meaning that it's content has not yet been generated and laid out).

I am making an educated guess that the `layoutSubviews` method is called later (when the `ViewController` is ready to render its view hierarchy?), but that the `commenceAnimationLoop` method spawns a thread that immediately executes in the background.

To summarise - what would be the best way to make my `animationLoop` operation wait for the view to layout before commencing?

To provide some high level context for what I am trying to achieve - I am using `NSOperation` to start a continuous animation. The idea being that I can provide an `endAnimation` method which would likely call `cancelAllOperations` on my queue. All this is done in the hopes I can provide a way of starting and then interrupting an infinite animation with the two methods `commenceAnimationLoop` and `endAnimation`. Perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree going down the route of multi-threading?

Comment: If you need layoutSubviews to run before your operation then you should't start the operation queue (use `setSuspended:YES`) until it have finished. You could start the operation queue (`setSuspended:NO`) in `viewDidAppear`...

Comment: The above worked and it's a really simple solution too. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need `layoutSubviews` to run before your operation then you should't start the operation queue before it that. You can prevent an operation queue from starting *additional* operations using `[myOperationQueue setSuspended:YES];`.

Since it will only prevent the queue from starting new operations you should suspend the queue before you add your operations to it.

After you view has loaded and `layoutSubviews` has run you can resume the operation queue again using `[myOperationQueue setSuspended:NO];`. One place to do this could be in `viewDidAppear`.